# How to not import system lib classes in java rhino lib script?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I use java Rhino lib as a script engine in my application,
so that users can write their own script to control the application to do some job,

but I don't want them to use the  java system lib classes in script ,ex:"java.lang.Sytem.exit()",

does anyone know how to do??  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Context.setClassShutter(ClassShutter)` on your context with an appropriate `ClassShutter` implementation that implements the method `visibleToScripts(String fullClassName)` in whatever way you wish to filter out (or in) whatever classes you want to have be usable from the scripts.

Comment: by the codes as below:

Context cx=Context.enter();  
cx.setClassShutter(new ClassShutter(){
   @Override
   public boolean visibleToScripts(String cls) {
    return false;
   }
   
  });

I can remove all the default java system package,and I can also add other host objects after this way, so it works!

Comment: by the way , after the version 1.7.6,here comes a new method "initSafeStandardObjects",which init a new scope object without any default system package .
refer to :https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/pull/171#event-282458660